# How do I add Financial Type

Tags: financial-types

I am setting up a new Price Field for a Webform I am creating and none of the Finincial Types in the drop down menu suit the Contribution so I need to create a new Financial Type. I cannot work out how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

To create a new financial type navigate to Administer > CiviContribute > Financial Types, and click on Add Financial Type.

See the manual for more details: [Key concepts and configuration](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/contributions/key-concepts-and-configurations/)